# Excel Javascript API: Changing Cell content and Formatting based on results from AJAX call

Tags: ajax, exceljs

I am trying to write an Excel Javascript plugin that takes the content from a selection in a sheet, and sends it to a remote endpoint using AJAX.  After the endpoint returns the script compares the data in selection and changes the font color according to the results from the Ajax call.

Here is the code snippet for the task at hand

See the code snippet below

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#align-terms-btn').click(generateSelectionColorMap);
        
    });
};


async function searchCentreeForExactMatch(term) {
   
    const result = await $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://remote-service/api/search/exact?q=" + term,
        headers: {
            "accept": "*/*",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + $('#centree-token').val()
        },

        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,

        

    })
    return result
}

async function generateSelectionColorMap() {
    await Excel.run(async (context) => {
        //var activeWorksheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet()
        

        let selectedRanges = context.workbook.getSelectedRanges();
        selectedRanges.load("address");
        selectedRanges.load("values");
        await context.sync();
        

        console.log(selectedRanges.address)
        console.log(selectedRanges.values)

        let selectedRangesStr = selectedRanges.address
        let selectionsArr = selectedRangesStr.split(",")
        
        for (var selectionRange in selectionsArr) {
            let sheetAddrArr = selectionsArr[selectionRange].split("!")
            let sheet = sheetAddrArr[0]
            let addr = sheetAddrArr[1]
            let range = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem(sheet).getRange(addr);
            range.load("address");
            range.load("values");
            await context.sync();

           
            context.trackedObjects.add(range)

            console.log(range.address)
            console.log(range.values)
            
            for (var row in range.values) {
                var cellColors = []
                for (var col in range.values[row]) {
                    exactMatchFoundFlag = false
                    await searchCentreeForExactMatch(range.values[row][col]).then((resolve, reject) => {
                        cellFontColor = "black"
                        if (resolve['elements'].length > 0) {
                            for (termHit in resolve['elements']) {
                                if (range.values[row][col] == resolve['elements'][termHit]['primaryLabel']) {
                                    cellFontColor = "green"
                                    exactMatchFoundFlag = true
                                }
                            }
                            if (!exactMatchFoundFlag) {
                                cellFontColor = "orange"
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            cellFontColor = "red"
                        }
                        
                        cellToUpdate = range.getCell(row, col)
                        cellToUpdate.format.font.color = cellFontColor

                    })


                }
                
            }
        }
        await context.sync();
        
    })
}
```

I am getting all the right cellFontColors, but I am unable to cause the text in the affected cells to change color.